# Macro de Excel Error 1004: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

Tags: excel, vba

Mi idea para el archivo es que cada vez que se cargue un campo, se asegure que el anterior ya se encuentre cargado.
Tengo la siguiente macro:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:D")) Is Nothing Then
        direc = ActiveCell.Address
        If Target.Count > 1 Then
            Range(direc).Select
        End If
        If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = "" And Target.Column > 1 Then
            MsgBox "Para continuar deberá llenar el campo: " & Target.Column - 1, vbExclamation, "Atención"
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

El error que me salta es:

> Se ha producido el error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución: Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Haciendo clic en Depurar me selecciona la línea:

```vb
If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = "" And Target.Column > 1 Then
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con este código? Por favor, incluye el mensaje de error completo.

Comment: El error que me salta es:
Se ha producido el error 1004 en tiempo de ejecución:
Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto.

Haciendo clic en Depurar me selecciona la línea:

 If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = "" And Target.Column > 1 Then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo estás obligando a no dejar ningún campo (celda) sin datos en las columnas A a la D. El problema es que cada vez que compruebas la celda actual haces retroceder al usuario una columna hacia atrás.

Cuando llegas a la primera columna e intentas evaluarla con el IF estás restando 1 a la primera columna con lo que Cells(2,0) no es válido y por eso te muestra ese error.

Por lo tanto tienes que evaluar primero que no estás en la primera columna y luego, con otro If....Then compruebas que la columna anterior tiene o no datos.

Prueba esto:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:D")) Is Nothing Then
        direc = ActiveCell.Address
        If Target.Count > 1 Then
            Range(direc).Select
        End If
        If Target.Column <> 1 Then

            If Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1) = "" Then

            MsgBox "Para continuar deberá llenar el campo: " & Target.Column - 1, vbExclamation, "Atención"
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Select

            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Parece funcionar bien con tu modificación. Te agradezco nuevamente la ayuda!